# Modify an object of a matrix

Tags: javascript, object, matrix

I have a matrix(matrix) of objects which have a property "state", initially set as false. Then I generated some random coordinates(randomCellsCoordinates) and put them in another matrix to set some of these object's "state" property to true.
Initially I tried to do a *forEach* loop as below:

```
// randomCellsCoordinates --> [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 0 ], [ 1, 1 ] ]
randomCellsCoordinates.forEach( pair => { 
  matrix[pair[0]][pair[1]].state = true
});
```

But this didn't work out by setting to true all of objects of this matrix.

```
[
  [ { state: true }, { state: true }, { state: true } ],
  [ { state: true }, { state: true }, { state: true } ],
  [ { state: true }, { state: true }, { state: true } ] 
]
```

Hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

fixed, basically i was creating the object in the wrong way, create objects like this

```
const test = new Object({ id: 123 })
```

is the correct way

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. But, I can't tell clearly how you fixed it. Can you provide a complete solution in your answer?